# stationary set,club,module theory,Auslander lemma,

Tags: set-theory, modules

Here http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-322-02/S0002-9947-1990-0974514-8/S0002-9947-1990-0974514-8.pdf I do not understand the **first two lines of the proof** of lemma 9,on page 550:What and why is there "dropping to a club"? Namely,how it follows that it suffices to prove our claim that $E$ below is stationary in $\kappa$. And how it follows from Auslander lemma that $(ii)$ continues to hold?
A detailed explanation of these two lines will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I can’t help with the Auslander lemma, but I can explain the part about dropping to a club. The assumption is that the set

$$E=\left\{\alpha<\kappa:\exists\beta>\alpha\text{ with }\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M_\beta/M_\alpha,H_\beta/H_\alpha)\ne 0\right\}$$

is stationary in $\kappa$. For each $\alpha<\kappa$ let $\varphi(\alpha)>\alpha$ be such that $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1\big(M_\varphi(\alpha)/M_\alpha,H_\varphi(\alpha)/H_\alpha\big)\ne 0$. Recursively define $\alpha_\xi$ for $\xi<\kappa$ by $\alpha_0=0$, $\alpha_{\xi+1}=\varphi(\alpha_\xi)$, and $\alpha_\eta=\sup_{\xi<\eta}\alpha_\xi$ if $\eta<\kappa$ is a limit ordinal. Then $\{\alpha_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}$ is a club (closed unbounded subset) in $\kappa$, so $E\cap\{\alpha_\xi:\xi<\kappa\}$ is still stationary in $\kappa$.

We now replace the sequence $\langle M_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$ by the sequence $\langle M_{\alpha_\xi}:\xi<\alpha\rangle$. This sequence clearly satisfies all of the conditions of the lemma except possibly (ii), and apparently there is some lemma by Auslander that implies that it satisfies (ii) as well.

For each $\xi<\kappa$ we have $\alpha_{\xi+1}=\varphi(\alpha_\xi)$, so $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M_{\alpha_{\xi+1}}/M_{\alpha_\xi},H_{\alpha_{\xi+1}}/H_{\alpha_\xi})\ne 0$. Thus, if simply re-index $\langle M_{\alpha_\xi}:\xi<\kappa\rangle$ as $\langle M_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\rangle$, forgetting about the original $\kappa$-sequence of submodules altogether, we have $\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M_{\alpha+1}/M_\alpha,H_{\alpha+1}/H_\alpha)\ne 0$ for each $\alpha<\kappa$. Finally, the definition of the $G_\alpha$ and $H_\alpha$ ensures that $H_{\alpha+1}/H_\alpha=G_\alpha$, so we may as well assume that

$$E=\left\{\alpha<\kappa:\operatorname{Ext}_R^1(M_{\alpha+1}/M_\alpha,G_\alpha)\ne 0\right\}\;.$$

Comment: Your explanation is clear.You have probably some typo on line 5:what is $\alpha_x i$?The Auslander's lemma says this:Let $R$ be a ring. The following are equivalent

       [1] $R$ has finite global dimension (the $\sup$ of p.d. $M\in R-Mod$) $\leq n$,        
       [2] every finite $R$-module has projective dimension $\leq n$, and
       [3] every cyclic $R$-module $R/I$ has projective dimension $\leq n$.

Comment: @user122424: Yes, I left out the backslash for `\xi`; fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Now,as we know what Auslander lemma says,why p.d. $M_{\alpha_{\xi +1}}/M_{\alpha_\xi}\leq1$?

Comment: @user122424: I can’t help there, I’m afraid: I know the set theory, but not the algebra.